# How to get details of per function app in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I'm running python v3 function app and it contains multiple functions with different bindings(cosmos, blob, http etc). I'm trying to get the details of this function app in application insights like no of request, exception raised during execution or number of request per function app and per function etc.
I'm able to run and get few details like request count. Now I'm trying to map request details with other tables like exceptions, request etc but not able to map and drill down to the particular function.

**For e.g Let suppose I have 10 function in function app and they run one after another based on output of previous function. Let say in any case flow got failed at any function. Now I want at which step/function my function app failed, details of error, successful and unsuccessful flow completion of function app**

Below are the some query I have used for monitoring purpose.

1. Request on first function to get the total number of request counts for function app.

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| where operation_Name =~ "function name"
| summarize RequestsCount=sum(itemCount) by cloud_RoleName,bin(timestamp,1d)
```

2. Request and Average Duration of functions

```
requests
| summarize RequestsCount=sum(itemCount), AverageDuration=avg(duration) by operation_Name
| order by RequestsCount desc
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the exception per function with:

exceptions
| extend OperationName = iff(operation_Name == "","[No operation name]",operation_Name)
| summarize Count = count() by cloud_RoleName, OperationName, type, method

To join with requests:

requests
| where timestamp > ago(24h) and success == false
| join kind= inner (
exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(24h)
) on operation_Id
| project exceptionType = type, failedMethod = method, requestName = name, requestDuration = duration, success

Keep it mind, if you catch an error yourself, the result of the function will be success.

You could also work with custom error logs in your functions where you maybe create a json object which will end up in the message column of the traces table. You can query further then:

traces
| where message contains "the error i am searching for"
| extend json = parse_json(message)
| project
timestamp,
errorSource = json.error_source,
step = json.step,
errors = json.errors,
url = json.url